# Is there any function of targets in binary classification decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

I was recently learning about decision tree and stumbled across a question which might be very silly but i am unable to understand it . That is if for a binary classification problem splits are used to build the decision tree , which in return works under entropy(Information Gain) right ? But entropy does not require the target variables right . Then how does the targets actually work ?
Or does entropy use it in some way ?

Comment: "...But entropy does not require the target variables right...". Entropy is just a way to calculate impurity. In DecisionTree - the calculation is based on target only

Comment: Thank you i later figured it out by looking at another tutorial